# Плавное изменение цвета текста

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Есть заголовок, при наведении курсором, цвет текста должен изменится слева направо, как прогрес бар. Что можно использовать для реализации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант с CSS анимацией:

```css
.progress_header {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.progress_header__first {
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.progress_header__second {
  color: #CC8810;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 1s ease-out 0s;
}

.progress_header:hover .progress_header__second {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress_header">
  <div class="progress_header__first">Расследование зашло в тупик</div>
  <div class="progress_header__second">Расследование зашло в тупик</div>
</div>
```